# Blocking UI interaction on a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, transactionmanager

I want to be able to block all UI interaction with a fragment until a callback occurs.

I have two buttons: ButtonA and ButtonB.

ButtonA shows a progress bar and kicks-off an asynchronous thread that calls-back to the fragment when it's done.  In the meantime, someone can press ButtonB which I don't want to allow.

My solution was to spin up another fragment which is transparent and intercepts all clicks.  However there appears to be delay between FragmentManagers commit() and the fragment actually working.
I've tried calling executePendingTransactions() but I still end up with threading issues whereby the fragment isn't in a state to accept onClick events before the user hits ButtonB.

Is there a more elegant solution?

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 0):

Call buttonB.setEnabled(false); after clicking buttonA.

```
CustomButton extends View {

     private boolean mIsEnabled = true;

     public void setEnabled (boolean enabled) {
        this.mIsEnabled = enabled;
     }


     @Override
     public void onClick() {
          if (mIsEnabled) {
               mOnClickListener.onClick();
          } else {
              return;
          }
     }


}
```

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned there are also custom views that implement onClick which don't expose setEnabled(bool)

Comment: They should expose a setEnabled method. All views should.

Comment: So you have custom button view? Add method setEnabled to it's code and override onClick method. to @Snicolas - yes, every view should expose setEnabled, but according to android docs - "The interpretation of the enabled state varies by subclass."

Comment: Yes it does ! @Semyon Danilov. In the same as onCreate varies from Activities to Fragment, and Applications. But still, all have one and the semantics are merely the same.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use a progress dialog fragment and set it to be non cancelable. It will cover the fragment and prevent the underlying fragment from receiving any touch event.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling another fragment,u can have another tranparent view with a progress dialog above the present view and make its visibility VIEW or GONE accordingly.Else u can simply show a prgress dialog with cancelable parameter as false.

Comment: I thing that @johncc do not want to allow user pressing button B, because it may cause errors and not because he do not want to hide progress dialog

Answer (score 0):

I didnt understood the question perfectly..
hope it may helps you.
when you adding transaprent fragment over it make the transparent layout  clickable=true

if a view is mentioned as clickable it does not pass touch events to below views.

sorry if i understtod your question wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Can't button A put its containing activity in a given state (with a boolean flag raised in its listener) and button B read that flag before doing any stuff ?

I think it's not only a UI issue here but also some presentation logic and mini-state machine that you should implement. This mechanism plus the fragment you already have should be enough to prevent gaps in the sequence of executions of UI Thread events.